# Android lint - apply a quick fix button is disabled on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-lint

After running "Android Lint" for detecting hardcoded strings, *`apply a quick fix`* button(bulb icon) is disabled on Android Studio 3.4.1 on Mac and windows. I'm not able to extract hardcoded strings. It's only showing `Provide feedback on issues of type HardcodedText`(check screenshots below)
Even on Android Studio 3.4.2 it's disabled that button. 
What's issue?

Macbook screenshot:

[image: macbook screenshot]

Windows screenshot:

[image: win]

Comment: is quick fix available for the sub-items of your node? activity_new_checkout.xml has an arrow to the right (left of it) - you can expand it. Expand it please and check whether sub nodes can be quick fixed

Comment: Did you try with Clear cache and remove `apply a quick fix`?

Comment: @Phash No its disabled for individual files too. Is it happening with you too?

Comment: @BlackBlind Yes tried that too.

Comment: what happened when you removed `apply a quick fix`?

Comment: @BlackBlind I tried with deleting build folder & invalidate caches. What do u mean by remove 'apply a quick fix'?

Answer (score 3):

Check `Show intention bulb` under `Settings > Editor > General > Appearance`.

It will show your bulb icon.

Comment: It's still disabled for Lint for XML files. On windows, It's enabled but it only shows 'Provide feedback on issues of type HardcodedText'.

Comment: try with a check and uncheck `Show intention bulb`

Comment: and last options to delete `.android` folder from your local. It will restore your settings.

Comment: can you try with delete `.android` , `.android3.4`, and `.gradle` files from `Local`. I do not know this will work or not.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be multiple errors on that xml file, make sure you branch out the inspection by clicking on the specific error and check if the bulb appears.

You can also check if Lint is configured to catch Hardcoded text in `Inspections` under `Settings > Editor > Inspections`.

Alternatively just double click the error pointed in Lint and check if Android Studio shows a squiggly line under the specific error. If not, might be a build error, compile and check again, by default it should highlight the issues. If you do see the squiggly line, Alt-Enter over the issue to see if it offers the quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

As per Android Lint is not an error but a warning. As a basic rule, you should never use hardcoded strings in your layouts also always use string resources (it means the all strings are stored in one separate file(`Strings.xml`) where they are easily changeable for different languages and so on). **But this way to definitely overcome this  problem.**

To convert a hard coded String to a string resources:

- put the curser on the hard coded string
- press ALT + Enter
- enter a name for your ressource
- click OK

**OR if you want to modify the code as follows:**

- If necessary, it adds the namespace xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
- If adds the attribute tools:ignore="HardcodedText" on the given element.